# Function using output buffer works in dev but not prod

Tags: php

I use this function in my views to position various content blocks.

```
function block(&$block = false) {
    if ($block === false) return ob_end_clean();
    return ob_start(function($buffer) use (&$block) { $block = $buffer; });
}
```

I never had problem with it until today. My blocks don't show up on this particular project.

Dev environment: PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze17 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (blocks show up)

Production environment where script fail (silently): PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u5 (cli) (blocks don't show up)

PHP logs don't show anything.

Can you help me find what is going on?

**EDIT:**

A bit more information on how I use this function.

Say I have a basic view `page.php`

```
<h1><?= $title ?></h1>
<div class="content">
    <?= $content ?>
</div>
<?php block($scripts) ?>
<script>
    // javascript here
</script>
<?php block() ?>
```

Then in my layout file `html.php`

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
...
<?php if (isset($scripts)) print $scripts ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT2:**

I use this class for my views.

```
class view
{
    public static $globals;
    public function __construct($file, $layout = null) {
        $this->file = $file;
        if ($layout !== null) $this->layout = $layout;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        extract((array)self::$globals);
        extract((array)$this);
        start:
            ob_start();
            include PATH_VIEWS . $file;
            if (!isset($layout)) return ob_get_clean();
            $view = ob_get_clean();
            $file = $layout;
            unset($layout);
        goto start;
    }
}


die(new view('page.php', 'html.php');
```

Comment: script throw no errors whatsoever, logs neither, how can I debug it? I'm used to var_dump/echo but fail to see how it'll help me in this case.

Comment: "but can't see how it'll help me in this case" --- check that **EVERY** line in your code does what it supposed to do

Answer (score 2):

`ob_end_clean()` returns only the top most output buffer. If prod and dev have different settings for output_buffer (http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) you will see different results. You can check this with `phpinfo()`

Since your output_buffer options match,  could you change your `include` to a `require`, just in case there's some path difference between the servers that's causing the path to mess up.

Comment: both environment have output buffer set to 4096 in php.ini, I did check this before posting my question but your comment made me look at `phpinfo()` on both just to be sure...